# Lowest continuous date without break

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and each record has a date. We can assume that a date range is contiguous if there's not a 3 month break. How can I find the start of the most recent contiguous date range?

For example, imagine if I had this data:

```
1990-5-1
1990-6-4
1990-10-28
1990-11-14
1990-12-19
1991-1-20
1991-4-30
1991-5-13
```

I'd like for it to return 1991-4-30 because it's the start of the most recent contiguous range of dates.

Comment: It is an interesting question.   What do you have so far?

Comment: What about Jun 1990 to Oct 1990? That's almost five months.

Comment: Or by "soonest" do you mean "closest to the current date"?

Comment: Yes, closest to the current date (assuming all dates are in the past.)

Comment: Does a range need to encompass two distinct dates or is one enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you're looking for.  Using my own table and column names as test data. This is on Oracle.

```
select * from (
  select * from sm_ss_tickets t1 where exists (
    select * from sm_ss_tickets t2 where t2.created_date between t1.created_date and t1.created_date+90 and t1.rowid <> t2.rowid
  ) order by created_date asc
) where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that "90 days" and "3 months" are not necessarily synonymous. :)

Comment: No was just some quick code, you'd want to use actual 3 months date calculation if it's important.

Comment: Is it correct that 3 months and 90 days may not be the same. In fact, 3 months may consist of as little as 30 days: 31-Jan to 1-Mar crosses two month boundaries so a DateDiff-type of function will return 3 for months or 30 for days. So it is imperative that "3 months" be strictly defined. That is why in technical specifications, one typically sees time periods specified in days rather than months. An approximation that may be off a day or two is much better than an approximation that may by off almost two whole months in a three month duration.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following would work:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT date'1990-05-01' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1990-06-04' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1990-10-28' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1990-11-14' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1990-12-19' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1991-01-20' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1991-04-30' AS dt FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT date'1991-05-13' AS dt FROM dual
)
SELECT MAX(dt) FROM (
    SELECT dt, LAG(dt) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) AS prev_dt, LEAD(dt) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) AS next_dt
      FROM d1
) WHERE ( dt > ADD_MONTHS(prev_dt, 3) OR prev_dt IS NULL )
    AND dt > ADD_MONTHS(next_dt, -3)
```

In the above, a date can only be the start of a contiguous sequence if there is no prior date within 3 months (either it is more than three months ago or it doesn't exist at all) and there is also a subsequent date within 3 months.

Comment: Try removing the final date from the list. Your second condition in the `where` clause will cause it to return the wrong date because there's no longer another date that follows it. Since we want the max date you don't need to check that anyway.

Comment: Well if there's no date following it, do we want to return that date? It can't be called "contiguous" if nothing follows it.

Comment: I just read the question again. My gut would say that yes, a single date counts as a contiguous series, but I'll admit I was thinking more in terms of the gaps.

Comment: I read "range" literally - but in any case I think it would be as simple as adding a condition that `next_dt` could be `NULL`: `AND ( dt > ADD_MONTHS(next_dt, -3) OR next_dt IS NULL )`

Comment: I can see your point completely. Of course from the perspective I've taken the whole `next_dt` thing is entirely unnecessary. I guess OP has to decide that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAG and LEAD.  Find the query below. I think it works fine.
tmp_year is the table I have created. tdate is the column.
The records in the table are

```
28-JAN-15
27-JAN-15
26-JAN-15
25-JAN-15
12-JUL-14
11-JUL-14
10-JUL-14
09-JUL-14
24-DEC-13
23-DEC-13
22-DEC-13
21-DEC-13
15-SEP-13
07-JUN-13
27-FEB-13
19-NOV-12
11-AUG-12
```

Please find the query which returns 25th Jan 2015.

```
select max(d.tdate) from (
select c.tdate,c.next_date,c.date_diff,lag(date_diff) over( order by tdate) prev_diff from (
select b.tdate ,b.next_date,(next_date-tdate) date_diff from 
(select a.tdate,lead(a.tdate) over(order by a.tdate) next_date from tmp_year a ) b ) c) d where d.date_diff<90 and d.prev_diff>=90;
```